# Use HTML dropdown to change which variable loads in django template

Tags: javascript, django

I am currently creating a pretty basic application using python django.

Currently I have a context that looks like this:

```
{'sheets': ['StockSummary(2)', 'StockSummary', 'Coverpage', 'Black-listedcountries', 'listingRCT', 'Longestlines'], 'StockSummary(2)': 'test1', 'StockSummary': 'test2', 'Coverpage': 'test3', 'Black-listedcountries': 'test4', 'listingRCT': 'test5', 'Longestlines': 'test6'}}
```

The first part 'sheets, is being used to create a dropdown list. When the drop down is changed I would like the associated string from the context to be loaded.

I have tried using string methods in a javascript function, like below, to load the variable:

```
function Loader(Val){
        var holder = document.getElementById('dataframe')
        holder.innerHTML = '{{'.concat(Val,'}}')
        
    }
```

In the above picture 'Val' is the value sent from the dropdown list. Unfortunately django doesn't render this how I would want.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks,
James

Comment: I think you should share more of that html, what is ".concat"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are conflating the django template language with Javascript. The template is only rendered once, whereas JavaScript is dynamic. In order to accomplish this, you would either need to load the context into a JavaScript object in the template, then choose the option you want, or make an API in your view to feed an Ajax function. It is hard to tell, however, without more code or HTML to see what you are doing.

As an example of the "API" option, using JQuery:

In your views.py file:

```
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    def sheets_api(request):
          data = {}
          if request.GET.get('sheet_name', None) is not None:
              sheet_name = request.GET.get('sheet_name')
              if sheet_name == 'Coverpage':
                  data['result'] = "test3"
              elif sheet_name == 'Stocksummary':
                   data['result'] = "test2"
              ...
          if request.is_ajax():
             return JsonResponse(data)
          else:
             return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

In your urls.py:

```
...
path('/api/sheet_name/', sheets_api, name="sheets_api"),
...
```

In your template:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$("#targetDropdown").change(function(){
    var selected_value = $("#targetDropdown").val();
    $.ajax({ url: '{% url 'sheets_api' %}?sheet_name=' + selected_value,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
               }).done(function(data) {
                    var mySelect = $('#newDropdown');
                    mySelect.empty();
                    mySelect.append(
                        $('<option>', {
                            value: data.result,
                            text: data.result
                        }, '</option>'))
                     }
               });
          });
</script>
```

You can also return results from the API in `views.py` as an array like so:

```
def sheets_api(request):
          data = {} 
          if request.GET.get('sheet_name', None) is not None:
              sheet_name = request.GET.get('sheet_name')
              if sheet_name == 'Coverpage':
                  data['result'] = ["test3", "test4", "test5"]
              elif sheet_name == 'Stocksummary":
                   data['result'] = ["test2", "test1", "test0"]
              ...
```

Then iterate over it and add more options in the dropdown if you want:

```
               ...
               .done(function(data){
                   var mySelect = $('#newDropdown');
                   mySelect.empty();
                   for (i=0;i<data.result.length;i++){
                        mySelect.append(
                            $('<option>', {
                                value: data.result[i],
                                text: data.result[i]
                            }, '</option>'))
                         }
                 });
```

I did not include the HTML here as that should be mostly self-explanatory. Now, without knowing more, this is basically just pseudocode (plus I just wrote this off the top of my head so it may have errors). If you post more details I can update my answer, but I think this should get you started.